# Create store procedure to disable and enable indexes

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have two below queries to, first of all, disable indexes and in another query enable them.
Here are my queries

```
--Disabling indexes
DECLARE @my_sql2 NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE cur_rebuild CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' +  i.name + ' ON ' + t.name + ' DISABLE' 
FROM sys.indexes i JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE i.is_disabled = 1 ORDER BY t.name, i.name;

OPEN cur_rebuild;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

   EXECUTE sp_executesql  @my_sql2;

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;

END;

CLOSE cur_rebuild;

DEALLOCATE cur_rebuild;

GO
```

And

```
--rebuilding indexes
DECLARE @my_sql2 NVARCHAR(200);

DECLARE cur_rebuild CURSOR FOR 

SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' +  i.name + ' ON ' + t.name + ' REBUILD' 
FROM sys.indexes i JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE i.is_disabled = 1 ORDER BY t.name, i.name;

OPEN cur_rebuild;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

   EXECUTE sp_executesql  @my_sql2;

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;

END;

CLOSE cur_rebuild;

DEALLOCATE cur_rebuild;

GO
```

I wonder if anyone can help me to create two store procedures for these two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to write an SP for each process.

Here is Disabling Indexes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisableNonClusteredIndexes]
 @tableName VARCHAR(100)
AS
SET nocount ON;
DECLARE @my_sql2 NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE cur_rebuild CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' +  i.name + ' ON ' + t.name + ' DISABLE'
 FROM sys.indexes I 
 JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id 
 WHERE i.is_disabled = 1 and t.name= @tableName
 ORDER BY t.name, i.name;
 OPEN cur_rebuild;
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_executesql  @my_sql2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;
 END;
 CLOSE cur_rebuild;
 DEALLOCATE cur_rebuild;
 GO
```

And here is Enable/Rebuild Indexes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EnableNonClusteredIndexes]
  @tableName VARCHAR(100)
AS
SET nocount ON;
DECLARE @my_sql2 NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE cur_rebuild CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' +  i.name + ' ON ' + t.name + ' REBUILD' 
  FROM sys.indexes I 
  JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id 
  WHERE i.is_disabled = 1 and t.name = @tableName
  ORDER BY t.name, i.name;
OPEN cur_rebuild;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
   EXECUTE sp_executesql  @my_sql2;
   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;
 END;
CLOSE cur_rebuild;
DEALLOCATE cur_rebuild;
GO
```